# should I use processes or threads for my application?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, process

I have an ARM device running a Linux 2.6 Kernel, with total ram of 64 MB RAM.

There is a data source, which consists of a meter that is queried by the Linux box, through RS485 and ModBus as app protocol.

There is another task, that consists of reading these values and making a json object, then HTTP POST to a specific server.

Network operation might be slower than serial, especially on low GPRS Coverage.

I need concurrency, program is written in C.

Which way would you have concurrency? Using select() or using pthreads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When analyzing this particular application there's really only one question relevant to choosing pthreads:

1. Do the sensor reader and network writer need to share an address space?

In this instance I think the answer is clearly "no". Of course that isn't the only possible question, but the only germane one. There are reasons to prefer separate processes:

1. the two halves of the application have no common code; RS485 is wildly different from HTTP/JSON
2. segregation of responsibility: if the RS485 side is waiting on a UART, do you really want to block the HTTP side?
3. letting the OS do its job so you don't have to: if using pthreads, you have to handle a lot of the synchronization and preemption that the kernel does for you for free and code that you don't have to write has no new bugs.

Further analysis would require more detail than you've given, but here is one additional way to think about the choice: threads were invented to mitigate some limitations of the process model. Unless you know that you are going to hit those limitations, use separate processes.

**added in response to comments**:

I half agree with psusi's suggested design. There need only be two processes, one (let's say the sensor reader, that's a fine choice) which forks one and only one http sender. The two processes can communicate using traditional IPC like a pipe. The sensor process sends data down the pipe when it has some and the child (http) process packs it up in json and sends it on its way.

It only takes two long-lived processes, it uses probably about the same amount of core as would a pthread implementation and it is far, far easier to get right.

Comment: So do you suggest using 2 process? So there are 3 options here: 1)Manual Threads on a single process 2) select() in a single process 3) Use 2 process

Comment: Yes, using select is a pain and threads can be too, and aren't necessary here.

Comment: @jacktrades, in this case I would imagine the simplest thing to do is have the serial port process be the parent... read the serial port and once you have a sample, `fork()` and let the background process take care of sending it to the web server while the foreground goes back to reading from the serial port.

Comment: @jacktrades, they don't need to communicate... that's why there's no point using threads.

Comment: @msw If we fork() a process each time we need to flush the sample to the network, if network goes down, then we would have many process, therefore the app can crash. Sure you don't suggest using pthreads? Keep in mind low MB Ram.

Comment: @jacktrades see "added" in my answer.

Comment: The child process can live as long as the parent does, which could be forever if your application requires it.

Comment: @msw When network goes slows or down, we will need a queue, that holds messages between serial process and it's network child. Should we use pipe as you suggest? Or Should we use message queue provided by Linux? Or even perhaps shared memory? A struct variable of many primitives is what is needed to be shared.

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works; it is not for ongoing dialog but single questions. Your last comment could make a good new question: "Is there buffering between a parent and child process connected by a pipe?". Please open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

select() is more efficient, because it avoids the context switching that comes with multiple threads. And threads would be more efficient than separate processes, because you avoid having to copy the data (unless you setup shared memory, but at that point you might as well have gone with threads). However, writing non-blocking I/O, as with select(), is harder to do and get right, and doesn't enjoy the multitasking that comes with multiple threads. And multiple processes is likely to be the easiest implementation, especially because you can use curl rather than writing the HTTP POST half yourself.

Comment: Why do you thinki you can use libcurl only on a process?

Comment: @jacktrades I made no mention of libcurl. He could use libcurl for a multithreaded solution, if that is what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need concurrency? Is the meter has to be polled in a strict time interval?

If the answer is YES: Just use two processes, one poll the meter data and write to a ring buffer in nand storage, the other read the data from the ring buffer and send HTTP data.

If the answer is NO: You don't need concurrency and non-block at all. Use a big loop in main() is enough.